# Can we install any module in cloud hosting?

Tags: python, django, cloud, hosting, cloud-hosting

It's my first app with Python and Django and I can't install all these modules in shared web hosting. So I have a query that can I install any module in cloud hosting such as:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==19.3.0 colorama==0.4.3
Django==3.1
iniconfig==1.0.1
install==1.3.3
more-itertools==8.4.0
olefile==0.46
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pluggy==0.13.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
py==1.9.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.0.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1
```

**Please guide me a way to host my Django website... Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you usually install modules with the help of `requirements.txt`. One of the best options for hosting small websites is heroku.com , you can find the docs and getting started here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/start

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try heroku and give you my update for it./